# Manipulate Javascript in an HTML file with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Regex extract a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378690/php-regex-extract-a-javascript-variable)

This is really probably just a simple string manipulation question that needs a good regex solution.

I have some javascript variables defined in an HTML page. I want to read the page in to PHP, identify the variable I want to change; and update it. The vars look like:

```
rsp.pageId = 'sports'
```

Just to be clear, my script will not know what the value is so in the example 'sports' could be anything; so it's a wildcard where the rest of the string is consistant. I don't know if it would be easier to wrap some comments around the var/value to get to it easier?

I appreciate the help. I'm playing with a DOM manipulation library so I thought about wrapping script tags around each variable and putting an ID on each. I think that would work but seems like the output would be a bit ridiculous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regex extract a javascript variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378690/php-regex-extract-a-javascript-variable) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951395/extracting-javascript-variable-values-via-web-scraping or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621940/how-find-value-of-javascript-variable-with-regex

Comment: really? the first two answers aren't related. why not edit them out.

Answer (score 0):

do you need the spaces around the equals, if not here - `preg_replace( "/rsp\.pageId='([a-zA-Z0-9])+'/", "rsp.pageId='blah'" );`
if so try here - `preg_replace( "/rsp\.pageId\s?=\s?'([a-zA-Z0-9])+'/", "rsp.pageId='blah'" );`