# read java script variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, variables, var

lots of results on this forum, 
    $temp = file_get_contents('http://example.com/weather/javascriptfile.js');
    echo "document.writeln(obTemperature);";

the javascriptfile.js contains

```
var obTemperature = "55";
var obIconCode = "01";
```

but this only works if the page loads, the javascript file is already loaded into memory,

Comment: i dont see how that code could possibly work you do noting with `$temp` for a start

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? What exactly do you think `var obTemperature = echo $obTemperature;` does?

Comment: and if that close doesn't suit, well then... you'll know what to do.

Comment: a scaping js file answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951395/extracting-javascript-variable-values-via-web-scraping

Comment: you can try with regex and the preg_match() php function.

    $input = file_get_contents('http://example.com/weather/javascriptfile.js');
    preg_match("/var (.*) = \"(.*)\";/", $input, $output);

the output array should look something like this :
    
    array(
        0 => 'var obTemperature = "55";'
        1 => '0bTemperature'
        2 => '55'
    )


The regex can be improved, this is for the idea ;)

Comment: $temp was read from _GET solution on stackoverflow not working

Comment: Patrick, just reading  obTemperature value from device for safety monitor for  my village as we have no climate controlled spots and people are dying,

Comment: yheah @PatrickQ stop killing the villagers ;)